# SQL object_definition returning definition of different, non-existent object?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, stored-procedures

I've encountered something I find very, very strange. I'm using something like `object_definition(object_id('StoredProcedureName'))` to get the definition of a stored procedure. However, I noticed that on some of our databases, the output was

`Create Procedure dbo.SomeOtherStoredProcedure`

This was an issue, because I was using the object_definition to alter the stored procedure, and when I tried to execute the new query it would say that the stored procedure 'SomeOtherStoredProcedure' didn't exist.

I know I'm not specifying the object type when using object_id, but (correct me if I'm wrong) since the returned definition is also a stored procedure, I don't think that's the issue here.

Is there some quirk to `object_definition` or `object_id` that I don't know about? What could cause this?

(SQL Azure, SSMS 2012)

Comment: It looks like this can happen when the stored proc is renamed. I'm not sure in that case on how to get the "true" definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Aaron mentioned, the cause is **sp_rename**. As [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql):

> Renaming a stored procedure, function, view, or trigger will not change the name of the corresponding object name in the definition column of the sys.sql_modules catalog view

You can get the updated object name from *sys.objects*. And a "true" definition can be found by fiddling with strings: find where the old object name is located in a corrupted definition and replace it with a new object name. Hope that's clear enough.